# Prism.js - How to get a link working in/with prism?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, prism.js

How can i get a link to work in prism?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2om8fjq/3/

```
<!-- Examples Link: -->

<pre>
  <code class="language-javascript">
    <a href="https://prismjs.com/" target="_self">https://prismjs.com/</a>
  </code>
</pre>
```